# Multiple transfers within one transaction?

Tags: python, web3py

I am writing a program in Python using the web3 library, which needs to make several translations in a single transaction. [Here](https://bscscan.com/tx/0x5a956c198a0db631e31d933ed02472791b5df237e9a2891da1673ff853131047) is an example. But I didn't find anything about it in the documentation. Some examples do several transactions through a loop, but it doesn't suit me at all.

Answer (score 1):

You have only two ways for this.

1. You need build your own contract, that do all this transactions by one contract call.
2. You need use multicall -- this is special contract, exists at every network. You send you transaction to multicall contract and run all by one call.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a smart contract is the only way to do it.

something like this:

```
function multiSwap(uint256 deadline, uint256 amountOutMinUniswap) external payable {

    uint256 amountOutMinBancor = 1;
    uint256 amountOutMinSushiSwap = 1;

    _tradeOnBancor(msg.value, amountOutMinBancor);
    _tradeOnSushi(IERC20(BNT).balanceOf(address(this)), amountOutMinSushiSwap, deadline);
    _tradeOnUniswap(IERC20(INJ).balanceOf(address(this)), amountOutMinUniswap, deadline);

}
```

Check out a great article by
Markus Waas - [Making multiple swaps](https://soliditydeveloper.com/multiswap)